# Need help translating a TSQL UNION to a JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, union

Long story short, I'm working in NAV and it has a query object, but those do not support UNION. In SQL, I would solve my issue via a UNION. Is there a JOIN that can get me the same result as this?

```
SELECT ID
      ,'' as 'Location ID'
      ,[Acc ID]
  FROM [dbo].[CRONUS Canada, Inc_$TestCarr]
UNION
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Location ID]
      ,[Acc ID]
  FROM [dbo].[CRONUS Canada, Inc_$TestCarrAcc]
ORDER BY [ID], [Location ID]
```

TestCarrAcc has a PKey of [ID,Location ID], TestCarr is only [ID]. This is because TestCarrAcc needs to support multiple per ID. I cannot alter these tables.

Essentially I am trying to retain the rows from TestCarr even when they match with TestCarrAcc (based on ID). Does that make sense? Is there even a way? If not, I have other solutions, they just would not be as elegant.

Comment: You wrote you are working in "NAV".  What is "NAV"?

Comment: I guess you are returning twice as many records? This can be achieved with a cross join to a table with two records... but to 'generate' that table inline requires a trick. One trick is using `UNION`.. which you can't use. The other trick is using an existing table. Is there any existing table that you can reference where you can write a query on it and return only tow records? Like using `ROW_NUMBER()` for instance? Does `ROW_NUMBER()` work? I despise these "SQL Helper" type programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite a `UNION` as a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

In your case as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(tca.ID, tc.ID)AS ID,
                CASE WHEN tc.ID IS NULL 
                    THEN tca.[Location ID] 
                    ELSE '' 
                END AS [Location ID],
                COALESCE(tca.[Acc ID], tc.[Acc ID]) AS [Acc ID]
FROM   [dbo].[CRONUS Canada, Inc_$TestCarrAcc] tca
       FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CRONUS Canada, Inc_$TestCarr] tc
                    ON 1 = 0;
```

Comment: Hey, this is awesome. Thank you. Now I just gotta do some google to fully understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the UNION in a view definition and then query the VIEW.